# disable the uitableview highlighting but allow the selection of individual cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

when you tap on a cell the row gets selected and highlighted.Now what i want to do is disable the highlighting but allow the selection.Is there a way around it.There is question that answers this but it disables both the selection and highlighting.

Comment: `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` add this in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

Answer (score 187, accepted):

You can just set the cell's selection style to "None" from Storyboard:

[image: See here]

Or from code:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

For Swift 3:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
```

For Swift 4 & above:

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

Comment: When I select to "none" I lose ability to work of of highlighted state. Can I make the background none/white without loosing that state?

Comment: In which function would this go? I'm guessing "cellForRowAt"?

Comment: You should do it in the cell not the tableview

Answer (score 27):

Change `UITableViewCell`'s `selectedBackgroundView` color to transparent.

```
    let clearView = UIView()
    clearView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() // Whatever color you like
    UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = clearView
```

or to set for a specific cell:

`cell.backgroundView = clearView`

Comment: This is the best options, since `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` sometimes breaks something deeply inside Apples animation logic.

Comment: then use instead ..`UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .None`

Comment: This is nice to use if you have selectable things within the cell.

Comment: Excellent solution. Putting this code in the cell's `awakeFromNib()` function works a treat

Comment: This option makes table view cell separator line not seen.

Answer (score 8):

Try setting cell selection style to None -

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

This will solve your problem

Answer (score 8):

For **Swift 3.0**:

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

Answer (score 6):

**For Swift:**

UITableViewCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;

Or when you subclass a cell in swift:

```
class CustomCell : UITableViewCell {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        selectionStyle = .None
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

**in swift 3**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To add a custom color use the below code. And to make it transparent use `alpha: 0.0`

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
cell.selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.27, green:0.71, blue:0.73, alpha:1.0)
```

If you use custom color and want to give it rounded corner look use:

```
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8
```

Also, use this for better animation and feel

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**For those looking for a programmatic way in Swift 3**

`cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the selection property of the cell itself in the storyboard
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 5** the best way is:

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Objc:**

> [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  _tableView.allowsSelection = YES;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    .. .. .. .. 
   [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
   . . . . .. 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution for swift 3,works even in editing mode

```
cell.selectionStyle = .gray
cell.selectedBackgroundView = {

    let colorView = UIView()
    colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
    //change the alpha value or color to match with you UI/UX

    return colorView
}()
```