# How can i stop the background colour of a UIView from disappearing when cell is selected?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a tableView which contains a label, image and UIVIew with a red background colour.

This is a picture of a row in my tableView which displays a label, image and a UIView that has a red background colour

[image: This is a picture of a row in my tableView which displays a label, image and a UIView that has a red background colour]

But whenever I select a cell, the background colour of the UIVIew disappears and all I can see is the label and image

This is the same row when I select it

[image: This is the same row when I select it]

I was wondering if there was a way to stop the background colour of the view from disappearing whenever the cell is selected.

Comment: cell.seletionStyle = .none aur refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233468/disable-the-uitableview-highlighting-but-allow-the-selection-of-individual-cells

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because cell selection style is set to default, change the `UITableViewCell` selection style to none.

Objective C:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Swift 3:

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

If you want to notify user has selected the cell, Maintain a property of `NSArray` which contains list of indexpath object.

Update the `NSArray` on delegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method change background color if indexpath exists in `NSArray`

Finally on didSelectRowAtIndexPath reload the selected row.

Comment: Okay thanks! But for user interaction purposes, how do I give feedback to the user that he/she has made a selection?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      //Just add this below line didSelectRowAt
      tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little better. I extracted from [MBProgressHUD/Demo](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD/blob/master/Demo/HudDemo/MBHudDemoViewController.m)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
       });
   }
```