# Hide grey color when cell is touched

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm making an app with a multiple cell selection (I use checkmark) like this

[image]

The problem is that when I click on a cell, it remains gray and is really bad. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to show grey selection at all:

- Select the `UITableViewCell` in Storyboard
- In Inspector, set `selected` to `none`

[image]

You can find more options to set it programatically [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233468/disable-the-uitableview-highlighting-but-allow-the-selection-of-individual-cells).

Answer (score 1):

try this code at `didSelectRowAt#`

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

or

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```